# assigning arrays from CSV with pandas module

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

If I have a file of 100+ columns, how can I make each column into an array, referenced by the column header, without having to do header1 = [1,2,3], header2 = ['a','b','c'] , and so on..?

Here is what I have so far, where headers is a list of the header names:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
df = pd.read_csv('outtest.csv')
for i in headers:
    data.append(getattr(df, i).values)
```

I want each element of the array headers to be the variable name of the corresponding data array in data (they are in order).  Somehow I want one line that does this so that the next line I can say, for example, test = headername1*headername2.

Comment: Could you provide an example input and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
```

If the headers are in the csv file, we can simply use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('outtest.csv')
```

If the headers are not present in the csv file:

```
headers = ['list', 'of', 'headers']
df = pd.read_csv('outtest.csv', header=None, names=headers)
```

Assuming headername1 and headername2 are constants:

```
test = df.headername1 * df.headername2
```

Or

```
test = df['headername1'] * df['headername2']
```

Assuming they are variable:

```
test = df[headername1] * df[headername2]
```

By default this form of access returns a `pd.Series`, which is generally interoperable with numpy. You can fetch the values explicitly using `.values`:

```
df[headername1].values
```

But you seem to already know this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're going for, so using a StringIO object to simulate a file object as the setup:

```
import pandas as pd 
import StringIO

txt = '''foo,bar,baz
1, 2, 3
3, 2, 1'''
fileobj = StringIO.StringIO(txt)
```

Here's the approximate code you want:

```
data = []
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj)
for i in df.columns:
    data.append(df[i])

for i in data: 
    print i
```

prints

```
0    1
1    3
Name: foo
0    2
1    2
Name: bar
0    3
1    1
Name: baz
```